# error in query in hibernate: SQL Error: 156, SQLState: S0001

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

the error is coming while runtime. pls help me to understand the problem.
i am using microsoft sql server

```
@Query("SELECT p from Product p JOIN FETCH StoreProductAvailability as spaFirst JOIN FETCH p.colors c WHERE spaFirst.available = true AND spaFirst.colorId <> 'null' AND spaFirst.colorId is not null and spaFirst.storeId = :storeId AND p.id = spaFirst.articleId AND c.colorId in (SELECT spaSecond.colorId from StoreProductAvailability spaSecond WHERE spaSecond.available = true AND spaSecond.colorId <> 'null' AND spaSecond.colorId is not null and spaSecond.storeId = :storeId and spaSecond.articleId = spaFirst.articleId)")
List<Product> findBlabla(int storeId);
```

```
Hibernate: select product0_.article_id as article_1_0_0_, colors2_.id as id1_2_1_, product0_.article_info as article_3_0_0_, product0_.commodity_group_id as commodit7_0_0_, product0_.info1 as info4_0_0_, product0_.material as material5_0_0_, product0_.article_name as article_2_0_0_, product0_.price as price6_0_0_, product0_.size_id as size_id8_0_0_, colors2_.color_id as color_id2_2_1_, colors2_.color_name as color_na3_2_1_, colors2_.article_id as article_4_2_1_, colors2_.article_id as article_4_2_0__, colors2_.id as id1_2_0__ from sf_article product0_ inner join sf_color_article_mapping colors2_ on product0_.article_id=colors2_.article_id inner join sf_store_product_availability_formatted storeprodu1_ on where storeprodu1_.available=1 and storeprodu1_.color_id<>'null' and (storeprodu1_.color_id is not null) and storeprodu1_.customer_id=? and product0_.article_id=storeprodu1_.article_id and (colors2_.color_id in (select storeprodu3_.color_id from sf_store_product_availability_formatted storeprodu3_ where storeprodu3_.available=1 and storeprodu3_.color_id<>'null' and (storeprodu3_.color_id is not null) and storeprodu3_.customer_id=? and storeprodu3_.article_id=storeprodu1_.article_id))
```

```
2020-04-08 22:09:33.258  WARN 6060 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 156, SQLState: S0001
```

```
2020-04-08 22:09:33.259 ERROR 6060 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Falsche Syntax in der Nähe des where-Schlüsselworts.
```

Comment: Please post at least the exception.

Comment: 2020-04-08 22:09:33.258  WARN 6060 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 156, SQLState: S0001
2020-04-08 22:09:33.259 ERROR 6060 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Falsche Syntax in der Nähe des where-Schlüsselworts.

Comment: I'd try to manually execute the query in any DB tool putting the existing storeId to make sure the query is correct itself.

Comment: no it is not, i get the same error in dbeaver sql editor

Comment: the problem must be here: inner join sf_store_product_availability_formatted storeprodu1_ on where 

there is no word after on

Comment: the problem is with my JOIN FETCH StoreProductAvailability as spaFirst, how to join it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
JOIN FETCH StoreProductAvailability as spaFirst
```

Is `StoreProductAvailability` a part of `Product`? Then you would do it as with `p.colors.`, like `join fetch p.availabilities`.

Or is it completely unrelated? Then you will need to rewrite your query, as you cannot join `fetch` unrelated entities/collections. Update: You can join unrelated entities from Hibernate 5.1+ onwards, though.

Comment: JOIN FETCH StoreProductAvailability spaFirst ON p.id = spaFirst.articleId